# Mac OsX - Phusion Passenger installation error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, macos, passenger, phusion

I'm trying to set up Phusion Passenger on Mac OsX and have been getting errors.  I installed the Passenger using Homebrew:

```
brew update
brew install passenger
```

successfully.  I then restarted the computer and ran

```
sudo passenger-install-apache2-module
```

and choose the option to install it for Ruby when prompted.  However, the setup doesn't complete successfully.  All of the returned code doesn't fit in this post but the following is the final section:

```
1 warning generated.
c++ -Iext  -D_REENTRANT -I/usr/local/include -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wno-long-long -Wno-missing-field-initializers -fcommon -fvisibility=hidden -DVISIBILITY_ATTRIBUTE_SUPPORTED -g -DHAS_ALLOCA_H -DHAS_SFENCE -DHAS_LFENCE -DPASSENGER_DEBUG -DBOOST_DISABLE_ASSERTS -std=gnu++11 -DHAS_UNORDERED_MAP -o buildout/common/libboost_oxt/boost/error_code.o -c ext/boost/libs/system/src/error_code.cpp
c++ -Iext  -D_REENTRANT -I/usr/local/include -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wno-long-long -Wno-missing-field-initializers -fcommon -fvisibility=hidden -DVISIBILITY_ATTRIBUTE_SUPPORTED -g -DHAS_ALLOCA_H -DHAS_SFENCE -DHAS_LFENCE -DPASSENGER_DEBUG -DBOOST_DISABLE_ASSERTS -std=gnu++11 -DHAS_UNORDERED_MAP -o buildout/common/libboost_oxt/boost/future.o -c ext/boost/libs/thread/src/future.cpp
c++ -Iext  -D_REENTRANT -I/usr/local/include -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wno-long-long -Wno-missing-field-initializers -fcommon -fvisibility=hidden -DVISIBILITY_ATTRIBUTE_SUPPORTED -g -DHAS_ALLOCA_H -DHAS_SFENCE -DHAS_LFENCE -DPASSENGER_DEBUG -DBOOST_DISABLE_ASSERTS -std=gnu++11 -DHAS_UNORDERED_MAP -o buildout/common/libboost_oxt/boost/once.o -c ext/boost/libs/thread/src/pthread/once.cpp
c++ -Iext  -D_REENTRANT -I/usr/local/include -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wno-long-long -Wno-missing-field-initializers -fcommon -fvisibility=hidden -DVISIBILITY_ATTRIBUTE_SUPPORTED -g -DHAS_ALLOCA_H -DHAS_SFENCE -DHAS_LFENCE -DPASSENGER_DEBUG -DBOOST_DISABLE_ASSERTS -std=gnu++11 -DHAS_UNORDERED_MAP -o buildout/common/libboost_oxt/boost/once_atomic.o -c ext/boost/libs/thread/src/pthread/once_atomic.cpp
c++ -Iext  -D_REENTRANT -I/usr/local/include -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wno-long-long -Wno-missing-field-initializers -fcommon -fvisibility=hidden -DVISIBILITY_ATTRIBUTE_SUPPORTED -g -DHAS_ALLOCA_H -DHAS_SFENCE -DHAS_LFENCE -DPASSENGER_DEBUG -DBOOST_DISABLE_ASSERTS -std=gnu++11 -DHAS_UNORDERED_MAP -o buildout/common/libboost_oxt/boost/thread.o -c ext/boost/libs/thread/src/pthread/thread.cpp
c++ -Iext  -D_REENTRANT -I/usr/local/include -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wno-long-long -Wno-missing-field-initializers -fcommon -fvisibility=hidden -DVISIBILITY_ATTRIBUTE_SUPPORTED -g -DHAS_ALLOCA_H -DHAS_SFENCE -DHAS_LFENCE -DPASSENGER_DEBUG -DBOOST_DISABLE_ASSERTS -std=gnu++11 -DHAS_UNORDERED_MAP -o buildout/common/libboost_oxt/boost/tss_null.o -c ext/boost/libs/thread/src/tss_null.cpp
mkdir -p buildout/common/libboost_oxt/oxt
c++ -O2 -Iext  -D_REENTRANT -I/usr/local/include -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wno-long-long -Wno-missing-field-initializers -fcommon -fvisibility=hidden -DVISIBILITY_ATTRIBUTE_SUPPORTED -g -DHAS_ALLOCA_H -DHAS_SFENCE -DHAS_LFENCE -DPASSENGER_DEBUG -DBOOST_DISABLE_ASSERTS -std=gnu++11 -DHAS_UNORDERED_MAP -o buildout/common/libboost_oxt/oxt/implementation.o -c ext/oxt/implementation.cpp
c++ -O2 -Iext  -D_REENTRANT -I/usr/local/include -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wno-long-long -Wno-missing-field-initializers -fcommon -fvisibility=hidden -DVISIBILITY_ATTRIBUTE_SUPPORTED -g -DHAS_ALLOCA_H -DHAS_SFENCE -DHAS_LFENCE -DPASSENGER_DEBUG -DBOOST_DISABLE_ASSERTS -std=gnu++11 -DHAS_UNORDERED_MAP -o buildout/common/libboost_oxt/oxt/system_calls.o -c ext/oxt/system_calls.cpp
mkdir -p buildout/common/libboost_oxt
rm -rf buildout/common/libboost_oxt.a
ar cru buildout/common/libboost_oxt.a buildout/common/libboost_oxt/boost/lockpool.o buildout/common/libboost_oxt/boost/c_regex_traits.o buildout/common/libboost_oxt/boost/cpp_regex_traits.o buildout/common/libboost_oxt/boost/cregex.o buildout/common/libboost_oxt/boost/instances.o buildout/common/libboost_oxt/boost/posix_api.o buildout/common/libboost_oxt/boost/regex.o buildout/common/libboost_oxt/boost/regex_debug.o buildout/common/libboost_oxt/boost/regex_raw_buffer.o buildout/common/libboost_oxt/boost/regex_traits_defaults.o buildout/common/libboost_oxt/boost/static_mutex.o buildout/common/libboost_oxt/boost/wc_regex_traits.o buildout/common/libboost_oxt/boost/wide_posix_api.o buildout/common/libboost_oxt/boost/winstances.o buildout/common/libboost_oxt/boost/error_code.o buildout/common/libboost_oxt/boost/future.o buildout/common/libboost_oxt/boost/once.o buildout/common/libboost_oxt/boost/once_atomic.o buildout/common/libboost_oxt/boost/thread.o buildout/common/libboost_oxt/boost/tss_null.o buildout/common/libboost_oxt/oxt/implementation.o buildout/common/libboost_oxt/oxt/system_calls.o
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/ranlib: file: buildout/common/libboost_oxt.a(regex_debug.o) has no symbols
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/ranlib: file: buildout/common/libboost_oxt.a(tss_null.o) has no symbols
ranlib buildout/common/libboost_oxt.a
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/ranlib: file: buildout/common/libboost_oxt.a(regex_debug.o) has no symbols
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/ranlib: file: buildout/common/libboost_oxt.a(tss_null.o) has no symbols
mkdir -p buildout/common/libpassenger_common
c++ -Iext -Iext/common -Iext/libev -Wno-ambiguous-member-template  -D_REENTRANT -I/usr/local/include -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wno-long-long -Wno-missing-field-initializers -fcommon -fvisibility=hidden -DVISIBILITY_ATTRIBUTE_SUPPORTED -g -DHAS_ALLOCA_H -DHAS_SFENCE -DHAS_LFENCE -DPASSENGER_DEBUG -DBOOST_DISABLE_ASSERTS -std=gnu++11 -DHAS_UNORDERED_MAP -o buildout/common/libpassenger_common/Logging.o -c ext/common/Logging.cpp
c++ -Iext -Iext/common -Iext/libev -Wno-ambiguous-member-template  -D_REENTRANT -I/usr/local/include -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wno-long-long -Wno-missing-field-initializers -fcommon -fvisibility=hidden -DVISIBILITY_ATTRIBUTE_SUPPORTED -g -DHAS_ALLOCA_H -DHAS_SFENCE -DHAS_LFENCE -DPASSENGER_DEBUG -DBOOST_DISABLE_ASSERTS -std=gnu++11 -DHAS_UNORDERED_MAP -o buildout/common/libpassenger_common/Exceptions.o -c ext/common/Exceptions.cpp
mkdir -p buildout/common/libpassenger_common/Utils
c++ -Iext -Iext/common -Iext/libev -Wno-ambiguous-member-template  -D_REENTRANT -I/usr/local/include -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wno-long-long -Wno-missing-field-initializers -fcommon -fvisibility=hidden -DVISIBILITY_ATTRIBUTE_SUPPORTED -g -DHAS_ALLOCA_H -DHAS_SFENCE -DHAS_LFENCE -DPASSENGER_DEBUG -DBOOST_DISABLE_ASSERTS -std=gnu++11 -DHAS_UNORDERED_MAP -o buildout/common/libpassenger_common/Utils/SystemTime.o -c ext/common/Utils/SystemTime.cpp
c++ -Iext -Iext/common -Iext/libev -Wno-ambiguous-member-template  -D_REENTRANT -I/usr/local/include -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wno-long-long -Wno-missing-field-initializers -fcommon -fvisibility=hidden -DVISIBILITY_ATTRIBUTE_SUPPORTED -g -DHAS_ALLOCA_H -DHAS_SFENCE -DHAS_LFENCE -DPASSENGER_DEBUG -DBOOST_DISABLE_ASSERTS -std=gnu++11 -DHAS_UNORDERED_MAP -o buildout/common/libpassenger_common/Utils/StrIntUtils.o -c ext/common/Utils/StrIntUtils.cpp
c++ -Iext -Iext/common -Iext/libev -Wno-ambiguous-member-template  -D_REENTRANT -I/usr/local/include -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wno-long-long -Wno-missing-field-initializers -fcommon -fvisibility=hidden -DVISIBILITY_ATTRIBUTE_SUPPORTED -g -DHAS_ALLOCA_H -DHAS_SFENCE -DHAS_LFENCE -DPASSENGER_DEBUG -DBOOST_DISABLE_ASSERTS -std=gnu++11 -DHAS_UNORDERED_MAP -o buildout/common/libpassenger_common/Utils/IOUtils.o -c ext/common/Utils/IOUtils.cpp
c++ -Iext -Iext/common -Iext/libev -Wno-ambiguous-member-template  -D_REENTRANT -I/usr/local/include -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wno-long-long -Wno-missing-field-initializers -fcommon -fvisibility=hidden -DVISIBILITY_ATTRIBUTE_SUPPORTED -g -DHAS_ALLOCA_H -DHAS_SFENCE -DHAS_LFENCE -DPASSENGER_DEBUG -DBOOST_DISABLE_ASSERTS -std=gnu++11 -DHAS_UNORDERED_MAP -o buildout/common/libpassenger_common/Utils.o -c ext/common/Utils.cpp
c++ -Iext -Iext/common -Iext/libev -Wno-ambiguous-member-template  -D_REENTRANT -I/usr/local/include -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wno-long-long -Wno-missing-field-initializers -fcommon -fvisibility=hidden -DVISIBILITY_ATTRIBUTE_SUPPORTED -g -DHAS_ALLOCA_H -DHAS_SFENCE -DHAS_LFENCE -DPASSENGER_DEBUG -DBOOST_DISABLE_ASSERTS -std=gnu++11 -DHAS_UNORDERED_MAP -o buildout/common/libpassenger_common/Utils/Base64.o -c ext/common/Utils/Base64.cpp
c++ -Iext -Iext/common -Iext/libev -Wno-ambiguous-member-template  -D_REENTRANT -I/usr/local/include -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wno-long-long -Wno-missing-field-initializers -fcommon -fvisibility=hidden -DVISIBILITY_ATTRIBUTE_SUPPORTED -g -DHAS_ALLOCA_H -DHAS_SFENCE -DHAS_LFENCE -DPASSENGER_DEBUG -DBOOST_DISABLE_ASSERTS -std=gnu++11 -DHAS_UNORDERED_MAP -o buildout/common/libpassenger_common/Utils/CachedFileStat.o -c ext/common/Utils/CachedFileStat.cpp
c++ -Iext -Iext/common -Iext/libev -Wno-ambiguous-member-template  -D_REENTRANT -I/usr/local/include -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wno-long-long -Wno-missing-field-initializers -fcommon -fvisibility=hidden -DVISIBILITY_ATTRIBUTE_SUPPORTED -g -DHAS_ALLOCA_H -DHAS_SFENCE -DHAS_LFENCE -DPASSENGER_DEBUG -DBOOST_DISABLE_ASSERTS -std=gnu++11 -DHAS_UNORDERED_MAP -o buildout/common/libpassenger_common/Utils/LargeFiles.o -c ext/common/Utils/LargeFiles.cpp
mkdir -p buildout/common/libpassenger_common/ApplicationPool2
c++ -Iext -Iext/common -Iext/libev -Wno-ambiguous-member-template  -D_REENTRANT -I/usr/local/include -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wno-long-long -Wno-missing-field-initializers -fcommon -fvisibility=hidden -DVISIBILITY_ATTRIBUTE_SUPPORTED -g -DHAS_ALLOCA_H -DHAS_SFENCE -DHAS_LFENCE -DPASSENGER_DEBUG -DBOOST_DISABLE_ASSERTS -std=gnu++11 -DHAS_UNORDERED_MAP -o buildout/common/libpassenger_common/ApplicationPool2/Implementation.o -c ext/common/ApplicationPool2/Implementation.cpp
c++ -Iext -Iext/common -Iext/libev -Wno-ambiguous-member-template  -D_REENTRANT -I/usr/local/include -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wno-long-long -Wno-missing-field-initializers -fcommon -fvisibility=hidden -DVISIBILITY_ATTRIBUTE_SUPPORTED -g -DHAS_ALLOCA_H -DHAS_SFENCE -DHAS_LFENCE -DPASSENGER_DEBUG -DBOOST_DISABLE_ASSERTS -std=gnu++11 -DHAS_UNORDERED_MAP -o buildout/common/libpassenger_common/ApplicationPool2/AppTypes.o -c ext/common/ApplicationPool2/AppTypes.cpp
c++ -Iext -Iext/common -Iext/libev -Wno-ambiguous-member-template  -D_REENTRANT -I/usr/local/include -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wno-long-long -Wno-missing-field-initializers -fcommon -fvisibility=hidden -DVISIBILITY_ATTRIBUTE_SUPPORTED -g -DHAS_ALLOCA_H -DHAS_SFENCE -DHAS_LFENCE -DPASSENGER_DEBUG -DBOOST_DISABLE_ASSERTS -std=gnu++11 -DHAS_UNORDERED_MAP -o buildout/common/libpassenger_common/AgentsBase.o -c ext/common/agents/Base.cpp
c++ -Iext -Iext/common -Iext/libev -Wno-ambiguous-member-template  -D_REENTRANT -I/usr/local/include -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wno-long-long -Wno-missing-field-initializers -fcommon -fvisibility=hidden -DVISIBILITY_ATTRIBUTE_SUPPORTED -g -DHAS_ALLOCA_H -DHAS_SFENCE -DHAS_LFENCE -DPASSENGER_DEBUG -DBOOST_DISABLE_ASSERTS -std=gnu++11 -DHAS_UNORDERED_MAP -o buildout/common/libpassenger_common/Utils/MD5.o -c ext/common/Utils/MD5.cpp
cc -Iext -Iext/common -Iext/libev -Wno-ambiguous-member-template  -D_REENTRANT -I/usr/local/include -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wno-long-long -Wno-missing-field-initializers -fcommon -fvisibility=hidden -DVISIBILITY_ATTRIBUTE_SUPPORTED -g -DHAS_ALLOCA_H -DHAS_SFENCE -DHAS_LFENCE -DPASSENGER_DEBUG -DBOOST_DISABLE_ASSERTS -o buildout/common/libpassenger_common/Utils/fib.o -c ext/common/Utils/fib.c
c++ -Iext -Iext/common -Iext/libev -Wno-ambiguous-member-template  -D_REENTRANT -I/usr/local/include -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wno-long-long -Wno-missing-field-initializers -fcommon -fvisibility=hidden -DVISIBILITY_ATTRIBUTE_SUPPORTED -g -DHAS_ALLOCA_H -DHAS_SFENCE -DHAS_LFENCE -DPASSENGER_DEBUG -DBOOST_DISABLE_ASSERTS -std=gnu++11 -DHAS_UNORDERED_MAP -o buildout/common/libpassenger_common/Utils/jsoncpp.o -c ext/common/Utils/jsoncpp.cpp
rm -f buildout/libev//libev.la
cd buildout/libev/ && make libev.la
make: *** No rule to make target `/private/tmp/passenger-bvASIZ/passenger-4.0.52/ext/libev/ev.c', needed by `ev.lo'.  Stop.
rake aborted!
Command failed with status (2): [cd buildout/libev/ && make libev.la...]
/usr/local/Cellar/passenger/4.0.52/libexec/build/common_library.rb:143:in `block in <top (required)>'
Tasks: TOP => apache2 => buildout/agents/PassengerHelperAgent => buildout/libev/.libs/libev.a
(See full trace by running task with --trace)

--------------------------------------------

It looks like something went wrong

Please read our Users guide for troubleshooting tips:

   /usr/local/Cellar/passenger/4.0.52/libexec/doc/Users guide Apache.html
   https://www.phusionpassenger.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Apache.html

If that doesn't help, please use our support facilities. We'll do our best to help you.

   https://www.phusionpassenger.com/documentation_and_support
```

Here is what I am using:
 Mac OsX 10.9.5
 Phusion Passenger 4.0.52 (installed with Homebrew)
 Ruby 2.0.0p481
 Rails 4.0.0
 Terminal as my command line interface

Any idea what could be causing the above?  How do I move past it?  I've been stuck on the Passenger installation for a few days and could really use the help.  Let me know if there's anything else I can provide as well.  Thanks, guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I then restarted the computer and ran
>   sudo passenger-install-apache2-module

passenger-install-apache2-module is supposed to work. Since it doesn't work, this is a bug which must be fixed. [I've taken note of it](https://github.com/phusion/passenger/issues/1288).

Anyway, you didn't have to run passenger-install-apache2-module in the first place. The Homebrew receipe already compiles the Apache module for you. In fact, if you look at the installation documentation, there are no instructions in the Homebrew section that tell you to run passenger-install-apache2-module. In the Homebrew caveats, you'll see that it specifically instructs you to edit the Apache configuration to insert the Phusion Passenger module snippet.